# UIPageViewController show the wrong page after adding third page

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

in my project I have a UIPageViewController that user can add new pages to it(it start with one page). every time user add new page UIPageViewController must show the current page(the user must be in the last page so he/she can add new page). after adding second page every things going fine but when user is in page2 and adding third page and scroll forward, UIPageViewController show the first page instead of showing the third page(for some reason I don't know, if user scroll backward everything working fine and UIPageViewController showing page1).

this is my codes to add new page:

```
class HomePageVC: UIPageViewController {

    private var pages = [SomeVC]()
    private var currentSomeVC: SomeVC!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
    
        dataSource = self
        delegate = self
        
        let someVC = SomeVC()
        pages.append(someVC)

        if pages.count != 0 {
            currentSomeVC = pages[0]
            setViewControllers(pages, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    
        if pages.count == 1 {
        
            delegate = nil
            dataSource = nil
        }
    }

    func addNewPage() {
        
        let someVC = SomeVC()
        pages.append(someVC)
        
        if delegate == nil, dataSource == nil {
            delegate = self
            dataSource = self
        }
    }
}

extension HomePageVC: UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = pages.firstIndex(of: viewController as! SomeVC) else {
            return nil
        }
    
            let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1
    
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
            return pages.last
        }
    
        guard pages.count > previousIndex else {
            return nil
        }
    
        return pages[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = pages.firstIndex(of: viewController as! SomeVC) else {
            return nil
        }
    
        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
    
        guard pages.count != nextIndex else {
            return pages.first
        }
    
        guard pages.count > nextIndex else {
            return nil
        }
    
        return pages[nextIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    
        if completed {
        
            guard let viewControllerIndex = pages.firstIndex(of: pageViewController.viewControllers?.first as! SomeVC), let viewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first as? SomeVC else {
                return
            }
            currentSomeVC = viewController
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reload UIPageViewController,

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    if !completed { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        self.dataSource = nil
        self.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error at runtime "Don't know about flushed view"

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `addNewPage()` method with the following:

```
func addNewPage() {
        
        let someVC = SomeVC()
        pages.append(someVC)
        
        if delegate == nil, dataSource == nil {
            delegate = self
            dataSource = self
        }
        setViewControllers([pages[pages.count-1]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

You're adding new viewControllers to your pageViewController but not setting you pageViewController to newly created one.

Hope It'll work for you.

Comment: I've created the demo for this and it's working fine.

Comment: Are you sure? Mine working fine when adding second page but after adding third page and moving forward the problem is happening. Is your working fine in this situation?